# C# Type parameter as Generic declaration

Tags: c#, generics

I am getting an error when trying to use a Type parameter when specifying the Type for a generic method.

> Error: 'JsonFilter.JsonDataType' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

```
public class JsonFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public Type JsonDataType { get; set; }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ...
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var result = jss.Deserialize<JsonDataType>(inputContent);//Error here
        ...
```

New Code

```
...
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
MethodInfo method = jss.GetType()
               .GetMethod("Deserialize")
               .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { JsonDataType });
var result = method.Invoke(jss, new object[] { inputContent });
filterContext.ActionParameters[Param] = result;
...
```

Reflection saves the day.  Thanks @Jason for the explanation that when type is specified as part of generic method ( <*Typename*> ), then it gets compiled into bytes.  Whereas when as property, it can be any type, only determinable at runtime.

UPDATE

For this specific problem, the following code is more concise.

```
var o = new DataContractJsonSerializer(JsonDataType).ReadObject(
    filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream);
filterContext.ActionParameters[Param] = o;
```

Comment: I may be completely off-base here, but it looks like you want the Generic Deserialize<T> method to work with a Type that is defined at run-time... I don't think generics work that way - they are nice and, well, "generic" at design-time, but they compile to type-specific code... yuck. my lack of understanding shows. 

Bottom line: I don't think what you're trying to do is possible. You can't use Generics with runtime-assigned types.

Comment: @Tao: It can be done using reflection. This is actually a very powerful technique in the right circumstances.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error

> Error: '`JsonFilter.JsonDataType`' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

is telling you exactly the problem.

```
var result = jss.Deserialize<JsonDataType>(inputContent);
```

Here, you are trying to pass `JsonDataType` as a type parameter to the generic method `JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>`

but here

```
public Type JsonDataType { get; set; }
```

you declared `JsonDataType` as a property of type  `Type`, but not as a type. To use a generic method you need to pass a type parameter (or, in some cases, let the compiler infer one). For example

```
var result = jss.Deserialize<string>(inputContent);
```

would be correct usage as `string` is a type.

Now, if you absolutely want to use the type that is represented by `JsonDataType` you can use reflection.

```
MethodInfo generic = typeof(JavaScriptSerializer).GetMethod("Deserialize")
                                                 .GetGenericMethodDefinition();
MethodInfo closed = generic.MakeGenericMethod(new [] { JsonDataType });
closed.Invoke(jss, new object[] { inputContent });
```

Comment: Hello, I am receiving Ambiguous match found exception on the following line:

typeof(JavaScriptSerializer).GetMethod("Deserialize")                                                .GetGenericMethodDefinition();

Do you have an idea on why the error is thrown? :(

Answer (score 5):

Since you can't add a generic type parameter to your class then you'll need to use reflection:

```
public class JsonFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public Type JsonDataType { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // ...
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        MethodInfo method = jss.GetType()
                               .GetMethod("Deserialize");
                               .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { JsonDataType });
        var result = method.Invoke(jss, new object[] { inputContent });
        //...
    }
}
```

**Original, incorrect answer...**

<strike>Can you use a generic type parameter instead of the `JsonDataType` property?</strike>

```
public class JsonFilter<TJsonData> : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // ...
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var result = jss.Deserialize<TJsonData>(inputContent);
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: "A generic type cannot derive from 'ActionFilterAttribute' because it is an attribute class" ... Can't make the attribute generic.

Comment: @Greg, In that case then I guess the updated answer, using reflection, is the way to go.

Comment: Yes.  Though, as you likely know, in other cases, what you originally put is obviously better.

Answer (score 2):

Try this something along these lines. I'll update it for your code in a sec.

```
typeof(IDependencyResolver).GetMethod("Resolve", new Type[] { })
                .MakeGenericMethod(type)
                .Invoke(this, null);
```

Here is a rough draft for you.

```
typeof(JavaScriptSerializer).GetMethod("Deserialize", new Type[] {} /* param types */)
    .MakeGenericMethod(JsonDataType).Invoke(jss, /*params*/);
```

Basically it uses reflection to invoke the generic method.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot pass a generic type argument in this way - try something like this:

```
public class JsonFilter<T> : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var result = jss.Deserialize<T>(inputContent);//Error here
    }
}
```

Rather than setting the type in a property, make your `JsonFilter` class generic so that you can pass the generic type argument through to the `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Comment: "A generic type cannot derive from 'ActionFilterAttribute' because it is an attribute class" ... Can't make the attribute generic.